# Are the halting problem proofs refuted by software engineering?

Tags: undecidability, halting-problem, simulation, c, decidability

Can D simulated by H terminate normally?
The x86utm operating system based on an open source x86 emulator. This system enables one C function to execute another C function in debug step mode. When H simulates D it creates a separate process context for D with its own memory, stack and virtual registers. H is able to simulate D simulating itself, thus the only limit to recursive simulations is RAM.

```
// The following is written in C
01 int D(int (*x)())  
02 {  
03    int Halt_Status = H(x, x);  
04    if (Halt_Status)  
05      HERE: goto HERE;  
06    return Halt_Status;  
07 }  
08  
09 void main()  
10 {  
11    H(D,D);  
12 }
```

**Execution Trace**
main() calls H(D,D) that simulates D(D) at line 11

**keeps repeating:**
simulated D(D) calls simulated H(D,D) that simulates D(D) at line 03 ...

Is this clear enough to see that D correctly simulated by H can never terminate normally? (because D remains stuck in recursive simulation)

> For any program H that might determine whether  programs halt, a
> "pathological" program D, called  with some input, can pass its own
> source and its  input to H and then specifically do the opposite  of
> what H predicts D will do. No H can exist that  handles this case.
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem

The relationship between H and D exactly matches the above specified pathological relationship.

**Simulation invariant:**
 D correctly simulated by H cannot possibly reach its own line 04.

When one applies a simulating (partial) halt decider to the Turing machine based proofs the same non-terminating result is derived as indicated by the exact match with the above criteria.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132462/discussion-on-question-by-polcott-could-h-correctly-decide-that-p-never-halts).

Answer (score -6, accepted):

```
// The following is written in C
01 int D(int (*x)())  
02 {  
03    int Halt_Status = H(x, x);  
04    if (Halt_Status)  
05      HERE: goto HERE;  
06    return Halt_Status;  
07 }  
08  
09 void main()  
10 {  
11    H(D,D);  
12 }
```

**Execution Trace**
main() calls H(D,D) that simulates D(D) at line 11

**keeps repeating:**
simulated D(D) calls simulated H(D,D) that simulates D(D) at line 03 ...

D correctly simulated by H can never terminate normally because D remains stuck in recursive simulation.

The fully operational source code of H/D and the x86utm operating system shows that H correctly matches a non-halting behavior pattern that is equivalent to infinite recursion.

H(D,D) fully operational in x86utm operating system: https://github.com/plolcott/x86utm

Source-code of several different partial halt deciders and their sample inputs.
https://github.com/plolcott/x86utm/blob/master/Halt7.c